# Exception while creating List on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having issues while creating a List on jsp . I am not sure whether its a bug(although unlikely) or there is some problem with the way i am implementing it .
When I try to store values in my list object I get this exception

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /OrderCheckOut.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

First I though that may be session object is not holding the value so I retrieved the value in a String and its working fine. But I am facing problems with list .below is my Jsp code .` <%
            try {
                Cart displayCart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("getValue");

```
         String firstname=displayCart.getProdRefCode().toString();
          //This is causing problem I suppose
         ArrayList<String>ProdRefCode=new ArrayList<>();
         ProdRefCode.add(firstname);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
    %><p> There is some problem..check..!
        <%
            }
        %>`
```

Can anyone help me put ..

Any help would be appreciated ..

Thanks

Comment: @Masud That won't fix the use of the diamond operator under 1.5.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Yes you're right.

Comment: I would also like to add that I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 and servlet version is 3.1.. if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace clearly says why this problem is happened. You probably use Java 5 but diamond operator is Java 7 feature. So, there is two solution

1. Update to Java 7
2. Do not use diamond operator like below declaration.

   ```
   List<String> ProdRefCode = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring ArrayList like this

```
ArrayList<String>ProdRefCode=new ArrayList<>();
```

Declare ArrayList Like

```
List<String> ProdRefCode= new ArrayList();
```

ie dont use the <> on the right side

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as five hours ago?

Comment: the one Masud gave had  <String> on the right side and he wrote "Do not use diamond operator ".so I wasnt sure what he was suggesting ..
@Dave and @ Masud  thanks for the help :)